# Access same method with different parameter

Tags: c#

I have a problem with passing number of parameters to a method:

```
Fruits(string Name1, string Name2, String Name3)
```

This method is working fine:

```
Fruits("Apple", "Orange","Pineapple");
```

I got this error

```
Fruits("Apple", "Orange");
```

> "No overload for method 'Fruits' takes 2 arguments."

Comment: Sorry but error message isn't clear? You know the concepts of `parameter` and `method` but don't know the concept of `overload`? I _strongly_ suggest to read beginner C# book first before you write more code about it.

Answer (score 2):

as the error says you have to add another constructor with 2 parameters

```
Fruits(string Name1, string Name2)
```

or you have to pass another value when you create your Fruits-object

```
Fruits("Apple", "Orange", "whatever")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a variable number of parameters:

```
 Fruits(params string[] fruits)
    {
          string firstparameter = fruits[0];
    }
```

And you can call this method with any number of parameters:

```
Fruits("Banana");
Fruits("Apple","Orange");
Fruits("Pineapple", "Whatever", "Idontknow");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as @fubo recommended. However I think you should read a proper C# tutorial and understand the basics. If you calling a method you must call it with number of parameters it requires and the correct types as well. You can either pas empty string to the parameter you want to ignore or anything else. But know well if you doing any further processing dependent on that parameter it will be affected.